# Как в нужное время вызвать функцию?

Tags: java, время

[image: цикл для проверки условия]

Всем привет, цель приложения - в определённое время проигрывать mp3 файл, я делаю это с помощью soundPlay. При запуске приложения на смартфоне появляется белый экран и ничего больше, если прибавляю громкость на телефоне, ползунок не появляется, в 17:40 музыка играет и через несколько минут приложение перестаёт работать.

Вопрос: как оптимизировать это приложение ? Например что бы условие if проверялось не бесконечное число раз, а раз в минуту. Или как вызывать soundPlay в определённое время ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть 2 возможных решения:

1. Использовать [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org). Будет много кода, но гибкое решение.
2. Использовать стандартные Executors. Немного логики по вычислению следующего запуска и все работает:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // вычисляем нужную задержку 
       Duration duration = Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.of(2019, 1, 9, 18, 43));
       long secondsToWait = duration.toMillis() / 1000;

       service.schedule(() -> {
           System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
           System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().toString());
       }, secondsToWait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
   ...
   private static ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
   ```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста 3 строчку (Duration duration = Duration.between(...)).
И как я понял вместо двух строчек с S.o.p. мне нужно расположить мою проверку условия, верно ?
А можно просто создать переменную типа Duration и поместить в неё значение 50, что бы проверялась точно каждая минута ? Спасибо

Comment: Или даже не 50, а 59 или 60.
И ещё, что значит (service.shedule(() ->) ?
Три скобки так и должны быть, или это опечатка ?

Comment: опечатки нет, это лямбда-выражение. 3-я строчка - это вычисление задержки до вызова сервиса (6-я строчка). как вы ещё будете вычислять - ваше дело, это всего лишь пример того, как запустить код в нужное время с точностью до секунды. вместо sout да, вам нужно расположить ваш код, который будет запущен в нужное время.

Comment: Так приложение будет запускаться не в какое-то определённое время. Нужно что бы музыка играла не через secondsToWait после запуска приложения, а что бы каждые secondsToWait приложение проверяло условие запуска музыки

Comment: Предложенные варианты решения не противоречат требованиям. Почитайте про ScheduledExecutorService, он позволяет сделать то, что вам нужно.